# Simple htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domains that end with .nl .com and .de. For each domain name I have a different language. My files are on the .nl domain. What I would like is the following for all domains:

- Redirect http://* to https://*
- Redirect http://example.* to https://www.example.*
- I Have the files on 1 server, and want them to look like it is on 3.

This is what I have on the main server (.NL)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.nl/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And this for the .DE

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.de/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.nl/$1 [P]
```

And this for the .COM

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.nl/$1 [P]
```

I've tried everything, but I could not figure it out.

Comment: rewrite all requests to https first, it's easier. Since everything is going to www.example.com just set the rules to use the [OR]: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [OR] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.de/$1 . I'm not familiar with [P] proxy server, but it seems like you aren't redirecting to a proxy server, just redirecting to .nl domain, a standard 301

Answer (score 0):

```
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

#primary site redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I believe that's all that's required, as you can see, you first redirect ALL requests that are not https to https example.nl, then you redirect anything that is NOT www.example.nl to https://www.example.nl

If I'm guessing wrong about what you need with [P] you can just replace I think [R=301,L] with [P], though I've never dealt with that configuration so I can't say for sure, but it's easy to test.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

this is more or less what we use for https. I think you're getting confused and not realizing that all you need to know is that something is NOT example.nl/$1, there's no need to list all those nots, since all of them are not example.nl/$1

Note the following, which are all NOT the second rule, all will get redirected:

```
https://example.nl
https://www.example.com
https://example.de
https://www.example.de
```

Since these are all not:

```
https://www.example.nl
```

they get redirected. (.*) means everything, including /.

There's a subtle thing that you need to be aware of with https, you have to have a certificate for ALL versions of all the domains, that's www/non www, or you get those browser alert popups for any initial domain/subdomain that does not have certificate support when the page initially loads. For example, if you don't have a certificate for example.com but you have one for www.example.com if a url comes in: http://example.com you'll get that browser alert, which is very bad for usability and makes it look like it's a scammer site.

I can't remember the exact ordering of processing, but I think that's how it works.